# java double sided Welch's t test

Tags: java, statistics, t-test, hypothesis-test

I have to implement the Welch's t test myself. To test my code I took the samples from Wikipedia as well as comparing custom examples with two different online calculators:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test
- http://www.statskingdom.com/150MeanT2uneq.html
- https://www.usablestats.com/calcs/2samplet&summary=1

The problem is, that my code outputs the correct value of p for either the Wikipedia samples or the calculators.
The error should be the factor 2 in the line marked with (!):

```
DescriptiveStatistics statsX = new DescriptiveStatistics(x);
DescriptiveStatistics statsY = new DescriptiveStatistics(y);
double meanX = statsX.getMean();
double meanY = statsY.getMean();
double sdX = statsX.getStandardDeviation();
double sdY = statsY.getStandardDeviation();

int nX = x.length;
int nY = y.length;
double t = (meanX - meanY) / (Math.sqrt(sdX * sdX / nX + sdY * sdY / nY));
double df = Math.pow(sdX * sdX / nX + sdY * sdY / nY, 2) / (Math.pow(sdX, 4) / (nX * nX * (nX - 1)) + Math.pow(sdY, 4) / (nY * nY * (nY - 1)));

TDistribution tDistribution = new TDistribution(df);
double tProbability = tDistribution.cumulativeProbability(-t);
double twoSidedP = 2 * (1 - tProbability);  //(!)
boolean hypothesisNotRejected = twoSidedP > significanceLevel;
```

With the factor 2 I get the correct results from Wikipedia for p (t is correct for all three). But the calculators as well as my own understanding tell me, that the test is already two-sided when using the cumulative probability.

Note: the DescriptiveStatistics as well as the TDistribution are taken from the Apache Maths API https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/overview-summary.html